# Ionic Js - Initialize iDangerous Swiper

Tags: slider, ionic-framework, hybrid-mobile-app, swiper.js

I've tried Swiper for web and all went really good.
Now i have to realize an iOS app that include Swiper in some slides.
I'm having some problems to activate my slide. I initialize my object Swiper within my controller:

```
app.controller('composeCtrl', function($scope){

    // sliders
    var swiperMontatura = new Swiper('.swiper-container-montatura', {
        initialSlide: 2,
        slidesPerView: 5,
        observer: true,
        observeParents: true,
        centeredSlides: true,
        paginationClickable: true,
        spaceBetween: 10,
        width: 1400
    });

});
```

If i launch `ionic serve` in the terminal to see the result in my browser, everything goes normally, after my build i don't see the same in my app, the slider doesn't work.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Hey , did you find a solution for that ?

Comment: I've added an Ionic feature for horizontal scroll

Answer (score -1):

Consider using `ion-slides` component as it's a `Swiper` integration for **Ionic** platform.
Basic usage can be found here: http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/directive/ionSlides/